# What part of speech is the word "another"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In this sentence

> He stayed *another* five years.

the word *another* isn't a determiner (because *five* is a determiner), and isn't a pronoun.

So what part of speech is it? Wiktionary says that *another* can only be a determiner and a pronoun.

Comment: I do believe "another" is an adjective that modified "five". "Five" is an attributive noun that modifies "years". "Years" is a noun that is a direct object of the unwritten "for" preposition.

Comment: It's important to distinguish category (noun, adjective etc.) and function (determiner, modifier etc.). "Another" and "five" both belong to the category (part of speech) **determinative**. Typically they function as "determiners", but when determinatives like "five" follow a determiner like "another" they become modifiers rather than determiners. So in your example, "another" functions as a determiner and "five" as a modifier".

Comment: Seems like an adjective to me.

Comment: Etymologically, _other_ is the comparative form of the PIE root [*_al-_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=al-) 'beyond'. It's a dual -- it always involves a pair of things or people, or else a division of something into two -- and duals have strange grammar. Plus, of course determiners are even more irregular.

Answer (score 3):

Determiners are noun markers and clarify nouns. "Another" belongs to the category of general determiners with "a", "an" , "any" etc., the plural of which is " other". "Another" is actually an indefinite article in combination with "other"(an+) and written as a single word meant to suggest an indefinite set/group or just 'a'/'an'  as indefinite as they are, but with a twist. Articles, possessives, numericals, quantifiers are all adjectives with a difference. Actually determiners are used to mean proximity, relationship, quantity and definiteness. Quantifiers tell us how many.

In the given example "five" is a quantifier. Another precedes 'five'. When "another" is placed before ' five' , its power of limiting extends over both 'five' and 'year' but serves the same function of an indefinite article which surprisingly A/An cannot fulfil. Wikipedia is right as it notes that 'another' serves the determining function but is more likely to be classified as an adjective in that it generally takes another determiner to complete the phrase although it still comes before other adjectives.

So ANOTHER is a general determiner with a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think *another* is a determiner in "another five years". We can also say "the five years" and *the* obviously is a determiner. *Five* evidently doesn't have to occupy the same "slot" before the noun as *another.* You can explain this various ways. [BillJ's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374206/what-part-of-speech-is-the-word-another#comment876567_374206) seems to say that "five" is not playing the role of a determiner here, but the role of "modifier". Or maybe there is more than one possible determiner slot before the noun.

There are many different kinds of "determiner-words"/"determinatives", such as articles, demonstratives, and quantifiers, and some of them can be used together.

Answer (score 0):

Methinks "another" is the determiner (meaning 'additional, extra') and is used with a singular countable noun (with uncountable and plural nouns, we usually use 'more', not 'other', with this meaning); "five" is a quantifier and "weeks" is a countable noun (or count noun). And "five weeks" is a noun phrase that functions grammatically as an adverb (i.e. adverbial noun) to modify the verb "stayed".